# Wood Carving of Garuda and Hanuman

Tags: sri-vaishnava, puja, garuda

Can wooden carving of shankha,chakra and thirunamam flanked by Garuda and Hanuman, as shown in the image below, be placed on the entrance of pooja room at home? Will it cause any adverse effects?[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is common to find this at the main entrance of Sri Vaishnava temples and homes. See [example of a house](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BO1XD.png).

Additionally it is printed on the covers of Srivaishnava books. See [an example](https://ia801009.us.archive.org/BookReader/BookReaderImages.php?zip=/29/items/SrivaishnavaBooks11-20/Amalanadhipiran%20Vyakhyanangal-pd12_jp2.zip&file=Amalanadhipiran%20Vyakhyanangal-pd12_jp2/Amalanadhipiran%20Vyakhyanangal-pd12_0000.jp2&scale=1&rotate=0),

It is also commonly displayed at the top of [wedding invitations](https://i0.wp.com/artistmayaweddingcards.com/wp-content/uploads/Big2f_yellow_1.jpg?fit=1082%2C640).

See it featured on home page of [Sri Ahobila Mutt,](https://www.ahobilamutt.org/us/home/welcome.asp) [Srimad Andavan Ashramam](https://www.andavan.org/).